# MX Mobile Device Detect stuck in endless loop

Tags: redirects

It works when I land on the mobile template from desktop, but when viewed from mobile I get an endless loop...

The mobile template:

```
{exp:mobile_detect:redirect location="http://csw.rizenbuilds.com" redirect="not_mobile"}
```

The desktop template:

```
{exp:mobile_detect:redirect location="http://mobilecsw.rizenbuilds.com" redirect="mobile"}
```

No clue where this loop comes from.